# How to find if a difference is statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a web crawler that scrapes items on an hourly basis and expect to get 375 items every time. In the past 10 runs, I have scraped the following number of items:

```
[360, 361, 363, 364, 368, 372, 375, 375, 375, 375]
```

On the 11th run, I only scrape 300. I want to determine whether or not this difference in item count on the 11th run is statistically significant as compared to the mean? That is, I want the to know if the subsequent run is significantly lower than the mean.

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by "expect to get 375 items every time"?  Your sample data looks more like you should expect to get AT MOST 375 items each time, but that you may fall a bit short of that some at least some of the time (so that your "expected value" would be below 375).

Comment: I meant that I expect to receive ~375 items. I want to know if a difference of 5-10% in item count is statistically significant so that I can send out an email alert to myself.

Comment: In hypothesis testing we ask the question, is the the unknown mean significantly different from 300? But you're asking the question, is 300 significantly different from a known mean 375? The answer to that latter question is undoubtedly yes since 300 =/= 375. I think the question you really want to ask is what is the probability of observing 300 or less scraped items given a mean of 375?

Comment: Testing statistical significance assumes sampling from a specific distribution (Normal, Poisson, Binomial, etc.). Do you know what your distribution is? With only 10 observations, it's not likely you can get an adequate empirical distribution - if you had more you could test what distribution it comes from.

Comment: @robin Your characterization of hypothesis testing is so narrow that it would eliminate all nonparametric tests.  These data certainly can be tested--even without distributional assumptions.  But note that this is not even necessarily a hypothesis testing situation: it is closer to constructing a prediction limit.

Comment: mendoncakr, Did you perhaps decide to make this test *after* you observed that $300$ seemed low, or did you decide to make it *beforehand* (as in, "I think I'll scrape for ten runs and then check the eleventh just as a test")? The difference matters a bit.

Comment: @robin.datadrivers: You seem to forget the huge class of distribution-free tests. Btw the setting in the OP is more related to univariate outlier detection than to hypotesis testing.

Comment: You'll want to get familiar with tests of outliers and control process tests.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://codepad.org/Qhce0sch ? You can tweak what you consider "significant" by tweaking p and epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're identifying the "300" by looking at the data (i.e. not based on characteristics that would pick it out before you saw it was 300), then you can't simply test for a difference from the rest.

For calculations of consistency to be meaningful, you *must* take account of the fact that you picked out the most-discrepant-looking observation to test.

There are a variety of ways to simulate this under the null, depending on exactly what you want to achieve, but unless you have a substantially larger sample, you'd probably need to make some parametric assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You also bring up testing difference from the mean, but your first question is about difference from 375 as "expected" (careful: in statistics and economics, "[expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)" has a specific meaning that may not be what you think). You do a statistical test to see if a given sample conforms to a hypothesis about a population - so if you expect the "population" mean to be 375, then you can test whether your sample of 10 has a mean of 375. You don't do a statistical test to see if a given value is different from 375 - of course 300 is different than 375. If you want to know if 300 is a big enough outlier to consider sufficiently different, then you can calculate sample statistics like mean, standard error of the mean, confidence intervals around the mean, etc. Or if your distribution is not Normal, then there are other parameters you could be after - for instance, if it is count data and it is skewed (so a normal approximation isn't appropriate), you could be looking at a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), which would give you different statistics

This could also get more complicated than you want it to, but most statistical tests assume independent observations. It may be that there is serial dependence in your observations, meaning the scrape now is dependent on the prior scrape. If that's the case, you've got a time series and that is an entirely different set of analyses to consider.

Comment: Welcome to cross-validated! Just a friendly pointer, asking the OP for clarifications ought to be written as comments.

Comment: Sorry! Still figuring this out.

Comment: There are some confusing elements in this post; in particular, one does not test whether a "sample ... has a mean of" $\mu$: one uses the sample to test whether the *population* has a mean (which was specified independent of the sample). But that's not even the question being asked here: the question is whether random variation can explain whether $300$ is so much less than the other values or not.